Error identifying the "coding system" of the custom bullets
I'm trying to setup Emacs from scratch in my Windows system with Emacs. I'm constantly getting below error whenever I try to close the emacs session.
I found this related post in reddit, but unlike that post, I'm getting the error only when closing emacs and not when saving the file.
Along with the below error, Emacs is also creating a *temp file* buffer whenever I try to close emacs, with ISO-LATIN-1 coding system which might be causing the issue. I'm not sure why this *temp file* is being generated. Checkout the screenshot below
screenshot of temp file with ISO-LATIN-1
ERROR:
These default coding systems were tried to encode the following
problematic characters in the buffer ‘ *temp file*’:
  Coding System           Pos  Codepoint  Char
  iso-latin-1-dos       41530  #x25BE     ▾
                        48541  #x25C9     ◉
                        48547  #x25CB     ○
                        48553  #x25CF     ●
                        48559  #x25CB     ○
                          ...             

However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
  iso-latin-1-dos cannot encode these: ▾ ◉ ○ ● ○ ● ○ ● •

Click on a character (or switch to this window by ‘C-x o’
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where ‘M-x universal-argument g a’ will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with C-g and edit the buffer
   to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
   the problematic characters).

  utf-8 gb18030 utf-7 utf-16 utf-16be-with-signature
  utf-16le-with-signature utf-16be utf-16le iso-2022-7bit utf-8-auto
  utf-8-with-signature utf-7-imap utf-8-emacs prefer-utf-8

this is the part of the code that customizes org-bullets that is probably impacting
(use-package org-bullets
  :after org
  :hook (org-mode . org-bullets-mode)
  :custom
  (org-bullets-bullet-list '("◉" "○" "●" "○" "●" "○" "●")))

screenshot of the error
screenshot of M-x describe-face

Why aren't you using UTF-8 for everything?

I was assuming these symbols of the bullets are also utf-8 symbols. I'm not sure how to verify if they are!!

Put point on one of the symbols, and do C-u C-x =, which will tell you all about it. But the issue here is that something is generating a temp file without specifying the right encoding. You need to figure out what that something is, perhaps with debug-on-message

the M-x describe-face (C-u C-x =) command gives me undefined when the point is at these bullets. Does that mean I don't have the font installed?

C-x = runs what-cursor-position, not describe-face

what-cursor-position give me following responses like these: Char: ◉ (9673, #o22711, #x25c9, file ...) point=31854 of 36490 (87%) column=32. I'm not sure what to make of this!!

IOW, you have to invoke what-cursor-position with a prefix argument. If the key binding C-u C-x = does not work for you, then try C-u M-x what-cursor-position.

Does this question help?

I tried the answer provided in that question, but that did not help

It's probably that your file has been encoded as iso-latin-1. You need to save it as utf-8. So try C-x RET f and specify utf-8 and save the file. Then reopen it and check the mode line: is there a U at the extreme left? Of course, since you are using Doom IIRC, they might have changed the format of the mode.

please checkout another screenshot I have added in the question. I'm getting this *temp file* only when i'm trying to close the emacs completely. And that buffer display the ISO-LATIN-1 coding system.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What's the question? You don't ask a question. The error message tells you what the error is. (This long comment thread is a sign that your question isn't clear.)

I'm not able to understand why or what is happening here. Which is why I'm not able to articulate the question properly. I'll try to figure it out further and see if I can make sense of it. Thank you for the help. Really appreciate it.
